# Request intutive explanation of xgboost leaf scores

Tags: xgboost

I refer to the stackoverflow question [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433209/can-someone-explain-how-these-scores-are-derived-in-this-xgboost-trees) regarding calculation of scores at the leaves by xgboost algorithm, once again. I have searched documentation a lot but could not find any intuitive explanation. Is it possible to have an intuitive meaning as to scores at the leaves in this picture and how (intuitively) these could have been calculated. Unfortunately, it is difficult for me to understand mathematics behind all this.

[image]

Comment: I have just answered the question here stackoverflow.com/a/55665330/3632002 . Feel free to leave me a comment if something's not clear.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort.